# Extract a word from a string based on position of bracket

Tags: string, excel, text-extraction

How do I extract the a word from a string only till the second occurrence of a closing bracket in excel

Eg . **Asus K55VD-SX313D Laptop (2nd Gen Ci3/ 4GB/ 500GB/ DOS/ 2GB Graph) (Passion Red)2 Write reviews and it will be helpful it creating value for other readers (hint)**

How do I extract only this **Asus K55VD-SX313D Laptop (2nd Gen Ci3/ 4GB/ 500GB/ DOS/ 2GB Graph) (Passion Red)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT` like this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",CHAR(1),2)))
```

The innermost function is `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",CHAR(1),2)
```

This substitutes the 2nd occurrence of `)` to `CHAR(1)` (some weird character you can see if you do `=CHAR(1)` in excel)

Next `FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",CHAR(1),2))` finds position of this character we just substituted into the substituted text.

And `LEFT` returns all the characters up to this position.

If you know that your strings can't contain, for example `@`, you can use this instead of `CHAR(1)`.

Comment: +1 for using SUBSTUTE to eliminate the first instance - very elegant! I was leaning towards FIND.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Thank you :) I like using SUBSTITUTE that way since it allows quite some flexibility for the nth instance of some character instead of nested finds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(")",a1,FIND(")",A1)+1))
```

I'm just looking to find the first ")"... after the first one